# Create a LightBox from a pre-existing photo/video gallery Javacript

Tags: javascript, class, lightbox

I am learning JS at the moment and i find myself struggling with a LightBox assignment.
I have a list of medias displayed on my front-page that i have fetched from a local JSON file.
It contains both images and videos.
I am trying to use the HTML nodes that were created from that to build a LightBox.

So far what i managed to do is :

-- LightBox.js --

- Create my LightBox class.
- Create a method to display the LightBox.
- Create a method to open the LightBox and hide the already existing content on the page.
- Create a method to close it.
- Create a method to display the previous media
- Create a method to display the next media.

-- index.js --

- Create a new LightBox from my class and pass it all the data that it needs.
- Call every methods from the class.

With the existing code whenever i click the prev or next button it updates to the right one but it only works once.
And when I click either button and try to click the other one it skips the item i opened the LightBox from.

Here is the code for that.

-- LightBox.js --

```
class LightBox {
  constructor(data) {
    this._data = data;
  }

  createLightBox() {
    const $wrapper = document.querySelector(".lightbox-container");

    if (this._data.classList.contains("post-img")) { //Class that only images medias have
      const lightBox = `
        <div class="lightbox">
            <i class="fa-solid chevron fa-chevron-left prev-media"></i>
            <div class="lightbox-text">
                <img alt="${this._data.getAttribute(
                  "alt"
                )}" class="lightbox-media lightbox-img lightbox-active" src="${this._data.getAttribute(
        "src"
      )}"/>
                <p>${this._data.getAttribute("alt")}</p>
            </div>
      <i class="fa-solid chevron fa-chevron-right next-media"></i>
      <i class="close-lightbox fa-solid croix fa-x"></i>
        </div>
    `;
      $wrapper.innerHTML = lightBox;
    } else if (this._data.classList.contains("post-video")) { //Class that only videos medias have
      const lightBox = `
        <div class="lightbox">
            <i class="fa-solid chevron fa-chevron-left prev-media"></i>
            <div class="lightbox-text">
                <video title="${this._data.getAttribute(
                  "title"
                )}" class="lightbox-media lightbox-video lightbox-active" autoplay loop src="${this._data.getAttribute(
        "src"
      )}"></video>
                <p>${this._data.getAttribute("title")}</p>
            </div>
            <i class="fa-solid chevron fa-chevron-right next-media"></i>
            <i class="close-lightbox fa-solid croix fa-x"></i>
        </div>
`;
      $wrapper.innerHTML = lightBox;
    }
    return $wrapper;
  }

  openLightBox() {
    const $wrapper = document.querySelector(".lightbox-container");
    $wrapper.style.display = "block";
    main.style.display = "none";
    header.style.display = "none";
  }

  closeLightBox() {
    const $wrapper = document.querySelector(".lightbox-container");
    const closeLightBox = document.querySelector(".close-lightbox");
    closeLightBox.addEventListener("click", function () {
      $wrapper.style.display = "none";
      main.style.display = "block";
      header.style.display = "block";
    });
    document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
      if (e.code == "Escape") {
        $wrapper.style.display = "none";
        main.style.display = "block";
        header.style.display = "block";
      }
    });
  }

  prev(mediaCollectionItem) {
    const mediaContent = document.querySelector(".lightbox-text");
    const prev = document.querySelector(".prev-media");
    prev.addEventListener("click", () => {
      mediaContent.innerHTML = "";
      const prevContent = mediaCollectionItem.cloneNode(true);
      const prevTitle = document.createElement("p");
      prevTitle.innerHTML = !prevContent.getAttribute("alt")
        ? prevContent.getAttribute("title")
        : prevContent.getAttribute("alt");
      prevContent.classList.replace("post-media", "lightbox-media");
      mediaContent.append(prevContent, prevTitle);
    });
  }

  next(mediaCollectionItem) {
    const mediaContent = document.querySelector(".lightbox-text");
    const next = document.querySelector(".next-media");
    next.addEventListener("click", () => {
      mediaContent.innerHTML = "";
      const nextContent = mediaCollectionItem.cloneNode(true);
      const nextTitle = document.createElement("p");
      nextTitle.innerHTML = !nextContent.getAttribute("alt")
        ? nextContent.getAttribute("title")
        : nextContent.getAttribute("alt");
      nextContent.classList.replace("post-media", "lightbox-media");
      mediaContent.append(nextContent, nextTitle);
    });
  }
}
```

-- index.js --

```
    let mediaCollection = document.getElementsByClassName("post-media"); //Class that all medias have either images or videos
    mediaCollection = [...mediaCollection];
    for (let i = 0; i < mediaCollection.length; i++) {
      mediaCollection[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
        const userLightBox = new LightBox(mediaCollection[i]);
        const renderLightBox = userLightBox.createLightBox();
        userLightBox.openLightBox();
        userLightBox.closeLightBox();
        userLightBox.prev(mediaCollection[i - 1]);
        userLightBox.next(mediaCollection[i + 1]);
        this.$body.appendChild(renderLightBox);
      });
    }
```

Thank you in advance for any tips or solutions you can find !
(Sorry if my question is unclear english is not my first language)

Comment: could this be turned into a runnable snippet? why `closeLightBox` method is attaching events whenever it's invoked (over and over)? same issue with other methods. it makes more sense to put all event attaching in the `createLightBox` method or possibly `open`

Comment: I don't think so as a lot of the logic for other components is missing on the code I posted. Indeed i could exctract the **eventListener** from the function itself and join my functions together as you mentioned. Thanks for that !